# Ionic/Cordova Contacts plugin returns Invalid Date on iOS after upgrade to Ionic 1.3

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Since I started using Ionic 1.3 (vs 1.0), the cordova-plugin-contacts module returns Invalid Date error on iOS 9. Still works on Android.

This has torpedoed my app so I am hoping someone can point me in the direction of how to troubleshoot it! Thanks.

The error

[image]

```
  var opts = { //search options
      // filter: '',                                 // 'Bob'
      //  multiple: true,                                      // Yes, return any contact that matches criteria
      fields: ['displayName', 'name'], // These are the fields to search for 'bob'.
      desiredFields: ['name', 'phoneNumbers'] //return fields.
  };
  $cordovaContacts.find(opts).then(function(allContacts) {}).catch(function(error) {
      //error is caught here;
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that in Ionic 1.3 the `birthday` field is returned by Cordova Contacts an invalid date (see screenshot below) and that all subsequent attempts to access the Contact's properties involve a serialization of the whole object that generates the error. My (hacky) solution was to copy the Contact properties except for birthday into a plain Javascript object and access it from there.

[image]

E.g.,

```
 allContacts.forEach(function (c) {
      if (c.name.givenName && c.phoneNumbers) {
        contacts.push({name: c.name, phoneNumbers: c.phoneNumbers}); // grab only the properties you need avoiding birthday
      }
    });
```

https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/issues/1233